# VB.NET Settings

Tags: vb.net, settings

I want to save settings in my program as follows.
I have an import button to open files. How can I make it so when I start up my program next time, they are already "imported" as a setting or something?
*Note - I have not tryed anything as I do not have the slightest clue how.

Comment: Do you mean you want something to store that you have imported a file when you open your program next time?

Comment: Bascially I am trying to use my.settings so that when a file is imported it saves the files location so when the program is started is opens those files

Comment: if you want to use my.setting, you can have a look at this page [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/108352-how-to-use-mysettings-in-vbnet/)

Comment: I already did. No help at all. I'm just looking for a code that will basically save the files location that I import so when I open my program next time, the imported files will still be set!

Comment: Then you may try to write your setting into a text file

Comment: I don't know how. Think you can write a script for me? I want it to do the following:
When they click the import button, open multiple files (done) then save them as a settings. Then on form load, open those files so I do not have to re-import them!

Answer (score 0):

The Code will be doing something like writing all filenames into the text file when you do the import. Then read the text file everytime you execute your program and check any content. You may need to amend the code to fit for your program

```
Private Const MySetting As String = "MySetting.txt"
Private Sub Log_into_File(ByVal Filenames() As String)

    Dim oFile As System.IO.File
    Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
    oWriter = oFile.OpenText(MySetting)


    For Each FName As String IN Filenames
        oWrite.WriteLine(FName & VbCrLF)
    Next    

    oWriter.Close() 

End Sub

Private Function Is_Imported() As Boolean

    Dim EntireFile As String
    Dim oFile As System.IO.File
    Dim oReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    oReader = oFile.OpenText(MySetting)

    EntireFile = oRead.ReadToEnd()

    oRead.Close()

    Return Trim(Replace(EntireFile, VbCrLF, "")).Equals(String.Empty)

End Function
```